# Someone knows why mocha throw me error even if everything passed in tests?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, should.js

[I get this error even when everything still right in test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5MPu.png)

[Here the part of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moUdQ.png)

And someone knows how to ignore this erros?

Comment: Please post your error and code as text, not images.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and add the code itself instead of posting images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `done()` before all tests have been evaluated, in fact even before you get the result for the requested URL. You need to move the `done()` call inside the `.end` callback. I would show you how if you pasted your code. But perhaps it's already clear from this description.